# SQL Server Reporting Services Mail Settings for Office365

Tags: powershell, reporting-services

I'm trying to set up email on SQL Server Reporting Services with Office 365. So I have properly configured Microsft tenant and mailbox.
For test on SQL machine I send an email using the Powershell Send-MailMessage script (details below):

```
$username = 'office@source.com'
$pass = get-content C:\pwd.txt | ConvertTo-SecureString #i'm have encoded password
$credentials=new-object Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $pass

$param = @{
SmtpServer = 'smtp.office365.com'
Port = 587
UseSsl = $true
Credential = $credentials
Encoding = 'utf8'
From = 'office@source.com'To = 'target@email.com'
Subject = '[TEST] subject for test'
Body = ' Testing SMTP from o365 '
}

Send-MailMessage @param
```

It's works OK, so the O365 and host configuration (e.g. network traffic, ports, tls) are correct.

Unfortunately, I am unable to run mails from SQL Server Reporting Services.
I'm try with difren setings of **rsreportserver.config** file. Part of setings below

```
<Configuration>
<RSEmailDPConfiguration>
<SMTPServer>smtp.office365.com</SMTPServer>
<SMTPServerPort>587</SMTPServerPort>
<SMTPAccountName>office@source.com</SMTPAccountName>
<SMTPConnectionTimeout></SMTPConnectionTimeout>
<SMTPServerPickupDirectory></SMTPServerPickupDirectory>
<SMTPUseSSL>True</SMTPUseSSL>
<SendUsing>2</SendUsing>
<SMTPAuthenticate>1</SMTPAuthenticate>
<SendUserName>AQAAANCMnd8BFdERjHo</SendUserName>
<SendPassword>RjHoAwE/Cl+sBAAAA0</SendPassword>
<From>office@source.com</From>
<EmbeddedRenderFormats>
<RenderingExtension>MHTML</RenderingExtension>
</EmbeddedRenderFormats>
<PrivilegedUserRenderFormats></PrivilegedUserRenderFormats>
<ExcludedRenderFormats>
<RenderingExtension>HTMLOWC</RenderingExtension>
<RenderingExtension>NULL</RenderingExtension>
<RenderingExtension>RGDI</RenderingExtension>
</ExcludedRenderFormats>
<SendEmailToUserAlias>False</SendEmailToUserAlias>
<DefaultHostName></DefaultHostName>
<PermittedHosts></PermittedHosts>
</RSEmailDPConfiguration>
</Configuration>
```

I'm reciving this error from Reporting Services:

**Failure sending mail: At least one error has occurred.Mail will not be resent.**

Comment: Office365 will not use for credentials username and password.  It must be an encrypted credential.  Also the credential and the From address must be from the same account.

Comment: when You set up your tenant to use SMTP You can! Its wery easy: 

https://sprawdzone.it/office-microsoft-365-i-smtp-5-7-3-authentication-unsuccessful-5-7-57-client-not-authenticated-to-send-mail/

please read carefully, my powershell script works, I have SMTP enabled. I send email notifications from other applications using this account. The problem is only with SSRS

Comment: This is an English website.    You cannot use a username and password.  This has been disabled for years.  See : https://itservices.usc.edu/office365/emailclients/?force_isolation=true

Comment: @jdweng ok, but it works - you have nothing to say please don't write. powershell script works, SMTP works - how to configure SSRS?

Comment: I doesn't work.  That is why you have this posting.  Make sure the FROM address and the User Credential are the same account.  The from address is 'target@email.com' and the credentials are $username,.  Are they the same account???

Comment: ok, try. setup tenant first, then mailbox and use this script 

I also have to worry you, if your MFP uses tls1.2 then you can also resign from oauth2 in favor of smtp - it works!. you have nothing to be nervous about, the only question is why you speak out despite your ignorance.

Comment: You cannot replace TLS with OAUTH.  They are two different protocols and do completely different functions.  Most servers require TLS to encrypt the data.  OAUTH is login credentials.  They are not the same.  You issue has nothing to do with either TLS or AUTH.  Servers Require the Fromm address and to be the same account.

Comment: I think you want to setup a RELAY.  The relay will not require the FROM address to match the credentials.  See following page look for relay.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow-best-practices/how-to-set-up-a-multifunction-device-or-application-to-send-email-using-microsoft-365-or-office-365?force_isolation=true

Comment: ok. im replace outh2 with smtp with many my clients - its work

this is not question about that. SMTP works beacose i can do that. you not.

im trying configure SSRS with o365 - this is the clue!

Comment: You need to use a relay.  A relay is a pass through that allows email to be sent without credentials.  The relay is trusted.  It uses Port 25 not encrypted.  I'm using a relay so I can send email from a linux machine through a Outlook 365 Windows Email Server.   The linux machine is using SMTP with Port 25.  The linux machine doesn't have windows credentials.  It is similar to a Printer sending emails on Windows.  You setup a smtp relay that does use credentials and the Office 365 email server takes the relay input and sends to destination.  See my link and look for relay.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, You must add some registry values to your system:

```
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v2.0.50727]
       "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
       "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
 [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\v4.0.30319]
       "SystemDefaultTlsVersions" = dword:00000001
       "SchUseStrongCrypto" = dword:00000001
```

after restart OS, SSRS sends reports with Office 365 mailbox.

The issue is that the SMTP library used by SSRS is old and hasn't been updated. Forcing TLS 1.2 and Forcing it for .NET resolve the issue.

Comment: I have tried adding in these keys (even in the WOW6432Node key and it still didn't work. Perhaps it's because I am running SSRS on a VM in Azure...?